# zlib Not Found in Mac High Sierra

Tags: macos, zlib

I am trying to build a program [unigen](https://bitbucket.org/kuldeepmeel/unigen) from source.  I run the program's `configure` script and get the error

```
...
checking for gzread in -lz... no
configure: error: zlib not found, see http://www.zlib.net
```

I verified zlib is installed via homebrew (although it is keg-only).  Based on other posts, I also verified xcode command line tools are installed via

```
xcode-select --install
```

If I run, `which zlib`, it does not print anything to the console.  I am not sure what else I can do to properly configure zlib or if there is something else wrong.

Comment: are you looking for `libz` (the library) or `zlib` (the Python tool)?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann The error message I get above was copied directly from the tool.  I can provide the full one if needed.  It says "zlib".  I did not know zlib was python only.

Comment: I was just looking at [this homebrew bug report](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-python/issues/234).

Comment: Since this issue is related to `make`, I do not think it is related to the Python issue.  For the sake of due diligence, I rebrewed my python3 but it did not clear the issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in the configure script. It must be getting an unrelated and unexpected error that is causing it to conclude that the link to `gzread()` failed when it probably didn't.

zlib is most definitely there in High Sierra, and links fine with `-lz`. I just tried a small program much like the test program in the configure script:

```
int gzread();
int main() {
    return gzread();
}
```

and compiled it with no problem in High Sierra using `cc -o test test.c -lz`.